# rails - how to make a GET request to action with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, get

I'm hoping this problem is a fairly simple one as I am relatively new to rails development. 
I am trying to make a get request from a controller with a specified action and pass required parameters. This is the relevant code in the helper class:

```
module ChartsHelper
  def chart_tag (action, height, params = {})
    params[:format] ||= :json
    path = charts_path(action, params)
    content_tag(:div, :'data-chart' => path, :style => "height: #{height}px;") do
      image_tag('loading.gif', :size => '32x32', :class => 'spinner')
  end
 end
end
```

and the corresponding action in the ChartsController:

```
class ChartsController < ApplicationController

  def week_events_bar_chart
    days = (params[:days] || 30).to_i
    render :json => {
      :type => 'AreaChart',
      :cols => [['string', 'Date'], ['number', 'subscriptions']],
      :rows => (1..days).to_a.inject([]) do |memo, i|
        date = i.days.ago.to_date
        t0, t1 = date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day
        subscriptions = Kpsevent.all.count
        memo << [date, subscriptions]
        memo
      end.reverse,
      :options => {
        :chartArea => { :width => '90%', :height => '75%' },
        :hAxis => { :showTextEvery => 30 },
        :legend => 'bottom',
      }
    }
  end
end
```

The routes file has the following:

```
resource :charts do
    get 'week_events_bar_chart'
end
```

However I get the following output when trying to perform this request:

```
 Started GET "/charts.week_events_bar_chart?days=14" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue May 22 00:31:48 +1200 2012
   Processing by ChartsController#index as 
   Parameters: {"days"=>"14"}
```

And the controller action is never called.
Is anyone able to help with this problem?

EDIT: rake routes output:

```
week_events_bar_chart_charts GET    /charts/week_events_bar_chart(.:format) {:controller=>"charts", :action=>"week_events_bar_chart"}
POST   /charts(.:format)                  {:controller=>"charts", :action=>"create"}
new_charts GET    /charts/new(.:format)    {:controller=>"charts", :action=>"new"}
edit_charts GET    /charts/edit(.:format)  {:controller=>"charts", :action=>"edit"}
GET    /charts(.:format)                   {:controller=>"charts", :action=>"show"}
PUT    /charts(.:format)                   {:controller=>"charts", :action=>"update"}
DELETE /charts(.:format)                   {:controller=>"charts", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your comment on console:

in rails `chart_path(x,...)` will generate a route to `ChartsController#show` with param id = x, which is by default `GET /charts/x`. By naming your parameter 'action', you fooled yourself, 'week_events_bar_chart' will just be the id in the restful route.

To your original code: 
`charts_path(x, params)` will route to `ChartsController#index` with format x, which looks like `GET /charts.week_events_bar_chart`, again calling it action fooled you.

What you need is the named route helper `week_events_bar_chart_charts_path` for your action.

But since you seem to want your helper action dependent, i recommend url_for.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for

```
module ChartsHelper
  def chart_tag(action, height, params = {})
    params[:format] ||= :json
    url = url_for({:action => action, :controller => 'charts'}.merge(params))
    content_tag(:div, :'data-chart' => url, :style => "height: #{height}px;") do
      image_tag('loading.gif', :size => '32x32', :class => 'spinner')
  end
 end
```

end

If you really want full path you pass `:only_path => false` to url_for.

Comment: This worked great - thank you very much for the code and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the route with a slash rather than a full stop after `charts`?

i.e

```
/charts/week_events_bar_chart?days=14
```

rather than

```
/charts.week_events_bar_chart?days=14
```

Comment: changing the path helper to: `path = chart_path(action, params)` causes the following error in the console

`Started GET "/charts/week_events_bar_chart.json?days=14" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue May 22 00:50:21 +1200 2012

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for ChartsController):`

Comment: Can you show the output from running rake routes in the terminal?