# Get output of Rails Action as string in Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 4.1.8 and I want to get the HTML output, as a string, from a certain controller inside a Helper which I'll later use in a View.

Assuming `app` were available at this point, this would be what I want. This, however, is just a conceptual example, not working code.

```
# pseudo-code
# widgets_helper.rb
module WidgetsHelper
  def widget_html(widget_id)
    app.get("/widgets/#{widget_id.to_s}.html")
    app.response.body
  end
end
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685401/rails-how-to-make-a-get-request-to-action-with-parameters) which appears to be related but I wasn't sure where to go with it.

I also read about [render_to_string](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string) but I'm not sure if that's taking me to a workable solution either.

**Update**

That previous question has a comment that also mentions [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106724/how-do-i-get-the-rendered-output-of-a-controllers-action-without-visiting-the-w)

Comment: The widgets are defined in your own rails app? If I understand correctly you should check out [cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells). Or otherwise please give some example to clarify.

Comment: Yes it looks like by incorporating cells I should get the functionality I'm looking for. A Widget can render as HTML for the `widgets#show` action, but there's also a `widgets#embed` action that generates JavaScript within which I want to include the entire HTML output of `widget#show`. Cells looks like it can help me do that.

Comment: Or just use ajax to embed them?

Comment: I'm using Ajax now, but where I'm using it is loaded in script tag in the first place. So right now my embedded Widget makes 2 calls. I'm going to refactor a lot of my code into Cells and it will help me a ton. Thanks again for the suggestion.